# Increase in print PDF file sizes after upgrading InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I'm recently facing a problem in InDesign after updating to version CC 11.4.1.102.

When I export a PDF for Printing the file is 20 MB, whereas in previous versions these files were only 1 Mb. Has anything changed in this version or is this a bug?

Comment: Hi Raj, I made some edits to you question to make it clearer. Feel free to [edit] yourself if I missed anything or changed anything too much!

Comment: How big the PDF is depends entirely on how big the document is, and how many images it contains. A 1,200-page document with large pictures on every page will quite naturally end up being much, much larger than a 35-page document that consists only of pure text. You don’t give any details, so there’s no way we can help you with what, if anything, has changed—for all we know, you’re simply exporting bigger, heavier documents now than you were before.

Answer (score 1):

A 20 Mb pdf file is quite small for printing. But as you expected a 1Mb file I gess you need to review your pdf export settings.

If you need a small file just configure the pdf settings to compress the images or resample them.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using different export settings? In any case 20 Mb sounds better than 1 Mb if you need to print this, since a larger PDF of the same content probably means better resolution.